# Open a file with line numbers in more (AIX)

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

How do I open a file in `more` mode with line numbers. I am using `ksh` on `AIX`

for `less` I use `-N` but for `more` it is not working.

`less -N filename`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the "view" command. This is the read-only mode of the vi editor and supports line numbers if enabled.

Comment: `nl file | more` maybe?

Comment: @ Mark Setchell Thank you. It is working, but how do I go to end of file in this mode

Comment: 'cat -n file | more' also does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this

`awk '{print NR,$0}' file | more`

Thank you :)